# Finite sum of exp(ikx)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

How can I proof that

$$\sum_{x=-L}^{L}e^{ikx}=L\delta_{k,0}$$

I feel that there should be some condition to state this, but my teacher only wrote this on his notes. How is possible something like that?

Comment: Do you know how to compute the sum of the first terms of a geometric sequence ?

Comment: Yes...I tried to split the sum and following the formula $\sum_{k=m}^{n} x^k = \dfrac{x^m-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$ but nothing appears..

Comment: The $L$ on the right-hand side should be $2L+1$ (just checking both expressions when $k=0$ gives this). Even then, the equation is only true when $k$ divides $2L+1$, so trust the result of your geometric series computation. (Try it by hand when $k=2$, for example, to see that it's not always true but that your geometric series computation gives the correct answer.)

Comment: So there are some hypothesis that are not mentioned?

Comment: @Gio Yes ${}{}{}$